# UnknownOperationException: GraphQl Appsync with AWS API Gateway

Tags: proxy, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync

I have integrated API Gateway as a proxy to AWS AppSync data plane via AWS CDK. I am trying to test the connection between API Gateway and AWS Appsync. I am getting to `UnknownOperationException` while testing calling appsync endpoint via the API gateway.

Below are the code snippet

```
const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, 'UserApi', {
  name: 'user-appsync-api',
  schema: appsync.Schema.fromAsset('lib/graphql/schema.graphql'),
  authorizationConfig: {
    defaultAuthorization: {
      authorizationType: appsync.AuthorizationType.API_KEY,
      apiKeyConfig: {
        expires: cdk.Expiration.after(cdk.Duration.days(365))
      }
    },
  },
  xrayEnabled: true,
});


   const createUserAPIGraphQl = apigateway.root.addResource('user-graphql');
    createUserAPIGraphQl.addMethod("POST", new apigw.AwsIntegration({
        service: 'appsync-api',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        subdomain: 'adsdasdsadasdasd',
        integrationHttpMethod: 'POST',
        path: 'user-graphql',
        options: {
          passthroughBehavior: PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,
          credentialsRole: ApiGatewayAppSyncRole,
          integrationResponses: [{
            statusCode: '200'
          }]
        },
      }
   ), {
    methodResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: '200',
        responseModels: {
          'application/json': Model.EMPTY_MODEL
        }
      },
    ]
   });
```

RequestBody

```
{
    "query": "query getNoteById { getNoteById(noteId: \"001\") { id }}"
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorType": "UnknownOperationException",
      "message": "Unknown Operation Request."
    }
  ]
}
```

**API Gateway Logs:**

```
Mon Jul 11 10:20:21 UTC 2022 : Endpoint response body before transformations: 
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorType" : "UnknownOperationException",
    "message" : "Unknown Operation Request."
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but I was triggering a GraphQL mutation via a HttpRequest.  I removed the path property from the requested and it got passed this error.

   `const req = new HttpRequest(this.graphQlEndpoint);
      req.method = "POST";
      //req.path = "/_bulk";`

If i enter an invalid mutation name i get a different error, e.g. 
Field 'documentUpdateXXX' in type 'Mutation' is undefined